# A divergent series related to the number of divisors of of p-1

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors of $n$. Is it known that the series
$$\sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{d(p-1)}$$
diverges?

This would follow immediately from the Sophie Germain Conjecture. Indeed, if there are infinitely many primes of the form $2p+1$ ($p$ a prime), then infinitely many terms of the series are equal to $1/4$, so the series doesn't even satisfy the most basic requirement for convergence! So, surely there must be a direct proof?

Comment: See Igor's answer for an argument along the lines you want. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27508/factors-of-p-1-when-p-is-prime

Comment: FYI: Since $1/d(n)$ is a multiplicative function that is $1/2$ on every prime, standard heuristics predict that the summatory function $\sum_{n\le x} 1/d(n)$ should have order of magnitude $x(\log x)^{1/2-1}$. (One could probably even write down the leading constant if careful.) On the further heuristic that random shifted primes $p-1$ aren't all that different from random $n$, one predicts that $\sum_{p\le x} 1/d(p-1)$ should have order of magnitude $x(\log x)^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Interesting, @Greg - thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since every divisor $k$ of $p-1$ either satisfies $k\le \sqrt{p-1}$ or $\frac{p-1}{k}\le \sqrt{p-1}$, we have $d(p-1) \le 2\sqrt{p-1}$. If we let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime, then since $p_n-1 \le n^2$ for all $n$ (an easy consequence of the prime number theroem...), we have

$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{d(p_n-1)} \ge \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{2n} \ge \frac{\ln N}{2}$,

so the partial sums diverge.

Obviously one can get much better bounds than these.

Comment: Nitpick: the prime number theorem has as an easy consequence the fact that $p_n-1\le n^2$ for all *sufficiently large* $n$.

Comment: Using $d(n)\ll n^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$, we obtain that the sum is $\gg N^{1-\epsilon}$.

Comment: Using the normal order of the number of prime factors of $p-1$, we obtain that the sum is $\gg N/(\log N)^{1+\log 2 + \epsilon}$. I do agree that it might be in fact $\approx N/ (\log N)^{3/2}$.

Comment: What I meant in the above comment was for the sum $\sum_{n\leq N} \frac1{d(p-1)}$.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, because I totally overlooked the following ridiculous idea:

Obviously $d(n)\leq n$ for every $n$. Thus $d(p-1)\leq p-1 < p$, so $1/d(p-1) > 1/p$ and the divergence follows from the divergence of $\sum 1/p$ (if one is willing to assume that).

Answer (score 0):

I did a heuristic analysis to study how this sum is growing. I calculated $d(p_n-1)$ and the sum and plotted the curve of the sum vs $n$. I obtained a very smooth curve which looked like a cumulative distribution curve. Next I did curve fitting to model this curve where the sum is the dependent variable and $n$ is the independent variable. The boundary condition I imposed was that the sum should be divergent. The following model was found to best fit the desired sum.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{d(p_n - 1)} \sim e^{a + b/x + c\ln\ln x}
$$

where $a,b$ and $c$ are suitable constants.

The true asymptotic formula could be different from the above but I believe this can give some hints in the direction of the true asymptotics.

Comment: Presumably your $N$ and $x$ are the same. Note that $e^{a+b/x+c\ln x} = e^a x^c e^{b/x} \sim e^a x^c$. So your model is simply predicting that the sum is asymptotic to a constant times a power of $x$. This is almost surely false: the sum is bounded above by $cx/\log x$ by the prime number theorem, and bounded below by $cx/(\log x)^2$ if there are infinitely many Sophie Germaine primes.

As I commented on the original post, the sum is probably asymptotic to a constant times $x(\log x)^{-3/2}$.

Comment: @GregMartin The bound $x/\log x$ is from counting the number of primes up to $x$. Here in the question, the prime counting is already done by indexing $p_n$, and $n=1, \cdots , \lfloor x \rfloor$. Thus, the heuristic $e^a x$ would possibly makes sense.

Comment: A fair point. I still think the conclusion is false, for reasons stated above.